# rails truncate wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Good day, I've this code in view, it generates

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:     <h3 class="<%= cycle('color_1', 'color_2')  %> ">
5:       <%= link_to sanitize(article.title),article %>
6:     </h3>
7:     <% output_text = truncate(article.text, 40, "...") %>
8:     <span><%= sanitize(output_text) %>
9:       <%= link_to ' ... full ->',  article %></span>
10:     <span style="display: none">
```

That's where i check truncate http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/37-how-to-truncate-text-in-ruby-on-rails

And if i write

```
<% output_text = truncate(article.text, 40) %>
```

I get

```
undefined method `reverse_merge!' for 40:Fixnum
```

Comment: For these kind of things you may want to look at the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) instead of at blog posts in the future :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<% output_text = truncate(article.text, 40, "...") %>`

should be

```
<% output_text = truncate(article.text, :length => 40, :omission => '...' ) %>
```